# DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity not generating an Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using EntityFramework code-first, I've created a simple `Foo` table. Here's my entity:

```
public class Foo
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

However whenever I try to insert a new row, I get a `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id'`. Why is this happening when I've added a `DatabaseGenerated` attribute? Deleting and recreating my table makes no difference.

Comment: Does the table that's created show that the `Id` column is marked as `IDENTITY`?  What's the underlying database?  MS SQL?  Oracle?

Comment: @DStanley The `Id` column isn't marked as identity. The underlying database is MS SQL.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: Has anything else changed?  The schema name?  The connection string?

Comment: @DStanley I'm using EF6. Nothing else has changed (and I keep recreating the DB, so I'm not sure it would matter if I had).

Comment: The attribute should *always* give rise to identity columns and EF not trying to insert `null`. If it doesn't, something else *must* be going on, probably a fluent mapping overriding it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Identities for `string` column types are not supported with SQL Server. (How do you expect such a string to look like?) To get this working you could - for example - add a computed column/user defined function in SQL Server that formats a string from an ordinary int identity column - as shown [here](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/custom-sequence-string-as-sql-identity-column.aspx).

Comment: I was following the lead of asp.net's [IdentityUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser.id(v=vs.111).aspx), which uses a string for the id. column. Any idea how the value is generated in this instance?

Comment: @Jonathan: I don't know, but I could imagine it's simply not database generated but a string you have to manually set as a unique value (like a user name or a guid converted to a string).

Answer (score 8):

1. you forgot the `Key` attribute. and there is no need to use `virtual` for primary key.
2. as mentioned by Slauma you can't use `Identity` for string datatype.

Try this code:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sadly this makes no difference.

Comment: ops! also the string can't used as Identity.

Comment: I had a problem with this and believe it or not I got it working by changing the property name of my Id from Id to {className}Id. I was using a Guid type though.

Comment: I know this is old, but is the `long` data type allowed with the [Key] attribute?

Answer (score 3):

I know that is an old thread, but for anyone in the future:

`DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)`

does not generate any values, it simply let EF know that DB suppose to generate the value as described in the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#value-generated-on-add-1). Therefore you must either set a default value in the database, in your model or assign an actual value in the controller.

Comment: This was the case for me, thanks I was not aware of this requirement from the SQL side

Answer (score 3):

For anybody reading this in 2020, 'Identity' attributes for string column types are supported using Entity Framework. For example, decorating a string type property in your C# class with the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute tag, then letting Entity Framework create the table through a database-first migration, and inserting that record through your program with Entity Framework methods (`AddAsync()`, `SaveAsync()`), auto-generates a string that looks like e.g. `'b652daab-9bb9-5143-a1ae-97a89232ea38'`.

MS SQL Server will not auto generate this value however (I trialled it with an Insert SQL statement). Instead, the program / Entity Framework seems to generate it.

Answer (score 1):

As Treadmeister stated, identity is working fine with `string Id` with at least Entity Framework Core 3+. My problem was passing an object from Web App with `Id: ""` which is `string.Empty` not `null` so EF Core was not generating new `Id`

Answer (score -1):

ANSWER EDITED IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS.

I had a different situation where I couldn't get DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity to generate an identity column and thought it worthwhile to post it in case it is useful to others as this was the first post that came up in my search for an answer.

I wanted to have Guid GUID as my Primary Key column, but then have an auto-incrementing int ID column as well. I could not get DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity to create the Identity column in this instance because it wasn't the PK, but I was able to force it by overriding the OnModelCreating behavior in the DbContext as follows:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            //get first property of entity with DatabaseGeneratedAttribute = DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity
            var idProp = entityType.GetProperties()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyInfo != null 
                 && x.PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DatabaseGeneratedAttribute>()
                 ?.DatabaseGeneratedOption == DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            //if it exists, set it to identity
            if (idProp != null)
                builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                    .Property(idProp1.Name)
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
                    .UseIdentityColumn();
        }
    }
```

As noted in the comments below, this is a sledgehammer approach and you need to be aware of limitations, but it does allow you to overcome a specific circumstance where DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity does not generate an ID if the ID column is not the PK.

Note that you will need to use ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate to ensure that the identity column is not updated.

Comment: It's certainly not to be promoted as a standard solution to override all `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute`s. In the first place, one may also have computed columns, or columns that should *not* be db-generated. In the second place, fluent mapping overrides attributes anyway, you shouldn't need this approach to find key columns.

Comment: Also, `UseIdentityColumn()` would fail on a string column, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps I was hasty posting this answer to this question.  Yes, I understand it won't work on a string column and I should have qualified my answer as such.  The situation I had was if I wanted an auto-incrementing int ID column that wasn't the PK, setting DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity won't set the database column to identity.  I'll edit the "answer".