# How can I get an item by a string key using web api?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I can't figure out how to hit an endpoint like "api/GetItems/AB123" (AB123 of course being a string) and have it return that item from my data set. I read the docs on the FindAsync() method and it seemed to indicate that it would accept a string by default. Is there something I need to do to 'id' before passing it into FindAsync()? My DB does not have a primary key, if that matters. (I can't change that either, this is legacy data and I have no control over schema)

My db doesn't have a PK ID field. I need to do the next best thing and target a unique string field.

My GET method:

```
        // GET: api/Items/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Item>> GetItem(string id)
        {
            var item = await _context.Items.FindAsync(id); // Error happens here: "InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int64'."

            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return item;
        }
```

Relevant from my model:

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to the Stack Overflow Community!!

Instead of find you could do .SingleAsync() like the below.
You could also do a .Where(x => x.ItemId == id).SingleAsync(). But this is up to you.

```
        // GET: api/Items/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Item>> GetItem(string id)
        {
            var item = await _context.Items.SingleAsync(x => x.ItemId == id);

            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return item;
        }
```

Comment: I'll mark yours because you were first, but the real reason for the bug was my model had incorrect data types. It didn't dawn on me because it errored at the .FindAsync() method. It didn't like that I had a completely different entity set to the wrong data type.

Answer (score 0):

From your error it is obvious that int is expected in FindById method. Can you check the field type in database but from your model I would say that you don't have correct type.
String can't be used as Identity in this way because SQL Server doesn't know how to generate value for that.

You can check this post for more details on that: [DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity not generating an Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027701/databasegeneratedoption-identity-not-generating-an-id)

So to conclude, you should check what do you really have in the database to determine is your model wrong.

If that is not the case and you do have a string in the db you should just retrieve item by using SingleAsync method (note that it will throw exception if the id is wrong).

```
var item = await _context.Items.SingleAsync(e => e.ItemId == id);
```

If you don't want an exception if the id doesn't exist you can use:

```
var item = await _context.Items.SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.ItemId == id);
```

which will return null for non existent id.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the model is fine. I'm able to return the full dataset without errors. Just not a single via a string key.